# Conditional Probability a Raffle

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

I would like to know the probability of each number coming out in a raffle in which we have from 1 to 25 and are drawn 15 numbers.

would be 1/15 or 1/25, or another percentage?

Similar problem:

What is the probability of getting two five consecutive with a six-sided die? The probability of each independent event is equal to 1/6. This gives us 1/6 × 1/6 = 1/36, 0.027 or 2.7%.

Comment: (Not sure)
p=probability of getting two five consecutive  ,
   r=probability of not getting two five consecutive  , 

p=1-r
p=1 - (5/6*5/6)=1-0.694=0.305

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about probability / mathematics instead of directly about programming / coding / programming tools / software algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

Probability of each number coming out in a raffle is `1/25`.

It is similar to the example you mentioned. Probability of getting a number from rolling dice is `1/6` whether you roll the dice once or multiple times.